# Creating a large csv file for testing file access

Tags: file-io, go

I want to create a 10 GB file that looks like:

```
prefix:username:timestamp, number
```

So an example is like:

```
login:jbill:2013/3/25, 1
```

I want to create a 10GB file, by creating random rows like the one above.

How could I do this in Go?

I can have an array of prefixes like:

```
login, logout, register
```

And also an array of usernames:

```
jbill, dkennedy
```

Comment: what about the time stamp and the number at the end, should they stay the same? What is the allowed range of these two if they should change on every entry?

Comment: @user1361315 Where is your actual problem? I can't see it.

Comment: @topskip timestamp can be any valid time in 2012.  the number can by any random number between 1-100.

Comment: @nemo do-my-homework-for-me? :)

Comment: @topskip ha!  I'm out of school and into the real world, just not that proficient with Go and buffers etc. b/c its a huge file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fileSize := int64(10e9) // 10GB
    f, err := os.Create("/tmp/largefile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    prefixes := []string{"login", "logout", "register"}
    names := []string{"jbill", "dkennedy"}
    timeStart := time.Date(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    timeDur := timeStart.AddDate(1, 0, 0).Sub(timeStart)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    size := int64(0)
    for size < fileSize {
        // prefix:username:timestamp, number
        // login:jbill:2012/3/25, 1
        prefix := prefixes[int(rand.Int31n(int32(len(prefixes))))]
        name := names[int(rand.Int31n(int32(len(names))))]
        time := timeStart.Add(time.Duration(rand.Int63n(int64(timeDur)))).Format("2006/1/2")
        number := strconv.Itoa(int(rand.Int31n(100) + 1))
        line := prefix + ":" + name + ":" + time + ", " + number + "\n"
        n, err := w.WriteString(line)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(n, err)
            return
        }
        size += int64(len(line))
    }
    err = w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Size:", size)
}
```

Output:

```
register:jbill:2012/8/24, 15
login:jbill:2012/10/7, 98
register:dkennedy:2012/8/29, 70
register:jbill:2012/6/1, 89
register:jbill:2012/5/24, 63
login:dkennedy:2012/3/29, 48
logout:jbill:2012/7/8, 93
logout:dkennedy:2012/1/12, 74
login:jbill:2012/4/12, 14
login:jbill:2012/2/5, 83
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a naive approach (1GB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    myfile, err := os.OpenFile("myfile", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer myfile.Close()
    var pos int
    var line string
    // sample: login:jbill:2013/3/25, 1
    line = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s, %d\n", "login", "jbill", "2013/3/25", 1)
    for pos < 1024*1024*1024 {
        bytes, err := myfile.Write([]byte(line))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        pos = pos + bytes
    }
}
```

which takes forever (1:16), because the output is not buffered. By adding bufio you can decrease the time dramatically

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    myfile, err := os.OpenFile("myfile", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer myfile.Close()
    mybufferedfile := bufio.NewWriter(myfile)
    var pos int
    var line string
    // sample: login:jbill:2013/3/25, 1
    line = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s, %d\n", "login", "jbill", "2013/3/25", 1)
    for pos < 1024*1024*1024 {
        bytes, err := mybufferedfile.WriteString(line)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        pos = pos + bytes
    }
    err = mybufferedfile.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Still 26 sec on my machine, I'd like to see a faster solution.

BTW: you need to do the random fileds, but that is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Disclaimer: I am a novice and the code should be taken with care. It might not be the best solution. It might not even be a good solution.

Comment: 26 seconds isn't that bad :)  so basically the buffered writer wraps the original file.  How does this add newlines?

Comment: See the line with the `fmt.Sprintf` - this adds a newline. The real application would be slower, since the `fmt.Sprintf` has to be called in every loop including random number generation and array lookup.